# Facing issue with Seaborn sample data set

Tags: dataset, seaborn, timeouterror

I'm learning seaborn and when I try to use seaborn sample dataset through jupyter notebook. I'm getting an error.

`import seaborn as sns`
`%matplotlib inline`
`tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')`

`Error:`

`TimeoutError Traceback (most recent call last)File ~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1346, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)1345 try:-> 1346 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,1347 encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))1348 except OSError as err: # timeout error`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1285, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)1284 """Send a complete request to the server."""-> 1285 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1331, in HTTPConnection._send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)1330 body = _encode(body, 'body')-> 1331 self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1280, in HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)1279 raise CannotSendHeader()-> 1280 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1040, in HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)1039 del self._buffer[:]-> 1040 self.send(msg)1042 if message_body is not None:10431044 # create a consistent interface to message_body`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:980, in HTTPConnection.send(self, data)979 if self.auto_open:--> 980 self.connect()981 else:`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1447, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)1445 "Connect to a host on a given (SSL) port."-> 1447 super().connect()1449 if self._tunnel_host:`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:946, in HTTPConnection.connect(self)945 """Connect to the host and port specified in init."""--> 946 self.sock = self._create_connection(947 (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)948 # Might fail in OSs that don't implement TCP_NODELAY`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py:844, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)843 try:--> 844 raise err845 finally:846 # Break explicitly a reference cycle`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py:832, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)831 sock.bind(source_address)--> 832 sock.connect(sa)833 # Break explicitly a reference cycle`

`TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

`During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

`URLError Traceback (most recent call last)Input In [3], in ()----> 1 tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py:596, in load_dataset(name, cache, data_home, **kws)594 if name not in get_dataset_names():595 raise ValueError(f"'{name}' is not one of the example datasets.")--> 596 urlretrieve(url, cache_path)597 full_path = cache_path598 else:`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:239, in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)222 """223 Retrieve a URL into a temporary location on disk.224(…)235 data file as well as the resulting HTTPMessage object.236 """237 url_type, path = _splittype(url)--> 239 with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:240 headers = fp.info()242 # Just return the local path and the "headers" for file://243 # URLs. No sense in performing a copy unless requested.`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:214, in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)212 else:213 opener = _opener--> 214 return opener.open(url, data, timeout)`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:517, in OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)514 req = meth(req)516 sys.audit('urllib.Request', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method())--> 517 response = self._open(req, data)519 # post-process response520 meth_name = protocol+"_response"`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:534, in OpenerDirector._open(self, req, data)531 return result533 protocol = req.type--> 534 result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +535 '_open', req)536 if result:537 return result`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:494, in OpenerDirector._call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, args) 492 for handler in handlers: 493 func = getattr(handler, meth_name) --> 494 result = func(args)495 if result is not None:496 return result`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1389, in HTTPSHandler.https_open(self, req)1388 def https_open(self, req):-> 1389 return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,1390 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)`

`File ~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1349, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)1346 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,1347 encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))1348 except OSError as err: # timeout error-> 1349 raise URLError(err)1350 r = h.getresponse()1351 except:`

`URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>`